# Using the Dropbox API or their interface, is it possible to get a ‘last viewed’ or ‘last accessed’ timestamp for file activity?

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I am attempting to get a list of timestamps for when files were last viewed or accessed, as in the file activity. Reading through the API documentation, I can see references to created and modified timestamps, but not viewed or accessed. Is this timestamp tracked by Dropbox at all and available to users through the API or through their web or native applications?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the Dropbox API doesn't return the last viewed/accessed timestamp for files in the file metadata, but I'll pass this along as a feature request. I can't promise if or when that might be implemented though.

File activity is available in the Dropbox UI though: https://help.dropbox.com/organize/file-activity